# WAMP Cannot start in Windows 8

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I recently installed Laravel on my system and was using `localhost:8000`as the server location. I had WAMP previously installed on my system and was using MySQL from that with Laravel.

Everything was working well. But when I restarted my machine, I could no longer run the WAMP. Its still showing the ORANGE ICON. When I tried to connect to the phpmyadmin, I got this error:

`#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).`

I checked the apache test port 80, and it shows `Server: Apache/2.4.9/ (Win64) PHP/5.5.12`

Can anybody help me? what might be the problem?

Comment: If the icon is orange then either the Apache or MySQL service has not started. As Apache is reporting its there when you test port 80. I think its safe to assume that the MYSQL Service has NOT STARTED and thats the reason for the icon being ORANGE. If its not started you will get the message saying`No connection could be made`

Comment: Look at the `mysql error log` if that does not help then look at the `Windows Event Viewer` for error messages from MYSQL

Comment: Can you explain why you gave a down vote?

Comment: Reinstalls are dangerous (people forget to backup database etc) and in almost all cases, unnecessary. I would guess you could have solved it by doing a `wampmanager->MySQL->Service->Install Service`

Comment: Sorry if it finds you disturbing, I already mentioned in the answer that it's not the best of all solutions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Checked the `mysql error log` and found the error. Fixed the error as specified in the Error Log and now it's working fine.

Comment: Don't know why this down voting for the questions and answers. But this really worked. Can any down voters explain me the reason?